# Converting Exponential value to Decimal Android

Tags: android, exponential

I have a String in the format of "6.151536E-8"

How can i convert it to a string or int as 0.000000061 ?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this if you want to have just 2 significant digits:

```
String str = "6.151536E-8";  
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(str);
bd = bd.round(new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
System.out.println(bd.toPlainString());
```

This prints: 0.000000062

If you want to round down to 0.000000061 then use RoundingMode.DOWN